# Strange output 'Array' with php / codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi I was following code igniter [user guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html) for forms and I encountered this strange output can anyone tell how to fix it?

Here is my code for beginning of the form

```
<?=$attributes = array('class' => 'email', 'id' => 'myform');?>
<?=form_open('email/index/', $attributes); ?>
```

I get form with id and class which I specified above but for some reason annoying Array text prints out and I cant figure out why, can anyone help? thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
<? $attributes = array('class' => 'email', 'id' => 'myform');?>
<?=form_open('email/index/', $attributes); ?>
```

The `<?= ?>` is a shortcut to `<?php echo ... ?>`, so your `$attributes` array would not only be created, but also printed.

The `<? ?>` is a shortcut for `<?php ?>` so that should fix it.

Comment: Oops totall missed that that was an echo. Good call.

I hate short tags :-)

Comment: Yea, I hate those tags too. Nothing but trouble :)

Answer (score 0):

You are evaluating an Array type variable to a string somewhere. It may have nothing to do with the form. Were you trying to echo/print somethign else up higher in the processing chain for debug that happens to be an array?